# Removing duplicate records in ever-growing database table by compairing it with incoming records - Python

Tags: python, mysql

I am going to store several thousand records each hour in MySQL table but the catch is if incoming records and table have duplicate records, either remove them from a table or from incoming data and then store the incoming data. I am going to use python for this task. but how I should handle the ever-growing size of the table and Memory issues.

I am thinking about pandas read_sql with chunksize generator for fetching table chunks and comparing it with incoming records and then deleting duplicate record from table and at last storing whole incoming data in a table. Will this work for me?

Comment: If you were using another language, I'd suggest doing something in-memory with a thread-safe hash set but that falls apart in Python land. Do you need this to be handling multiple requests in parallel? You could probably get away with hashing the content of the row and storing it in an indexed field in mysql, then querying to see if that row already exists. It's an additional network round trip for every insert, but it offloads the heavy lifting from Python to MySQL. You'd have to handle the case of the same row being received twice at nearly the same time

Comment: If there is a record in the table that would be duplicated by adding a record from the incoming data, I think it makes sense _not_ to store that record at all. This can be achieved with MySQL's [uniqueness constraint](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-unique-constraint/) on whatever columns make up what is considered a duplicate. Whatever application is handling the inserting of data would have to deal with the MySQL error that pops up, but that is simple with clients like [`pymysql`](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)